# react-transition-group CSSTransition, conditional with null

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

Trying to get a simple fade in/out transition working.

I've tried moving the `<CSSTransition>` around into different areas to no avail. I'm using this successfully in another component that's mapping children but can't see why it wouldn't work in this case since I'm rendering it together with the child component, if the child gets returned at all.

**Child component**

```
const Error = (props) => {
  return (
    <CSSTransition timeout={400} classNames={errorTransition}>
      <span> {props.errorString} </span>
    </CSSTransition>
  )
}
```

**Parent component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import type { InfoState } from './state';
import { closeError } from './actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state: {info: InfoState}) => ({
  info: state.info.data.info,
  infoError: state.info.infoError,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  closeError: () => dispatch(closeError()),
});

class Parent extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = { info: this.props.info };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ info: e.target.value });
    this.props.closeError();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.info === null) {
      return (
        <div className="info-wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.info ? this.state.info : '' }
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="info-error">
          { this.props.infoError !== ''
            ? <Error 
                key={this.state.info} 
                errorString={this.props.infoError} 
              />
            : null
           }
        </div>
      )
    }
    return ( <div> things </div> )
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.errorTransition-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.errorTransition-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 400ms ease-out;
}
.errorTransition-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.errorTransition-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: all 400ms ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Can you share everything inside the components? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this condition: `this.props.infoError !== ' '` returns true?

Comment: @ladyk yep! I'm catching the error every time correctly

Comment: so I think the case is you're not passing **'in'** parameter in CSSTransition, please look at the example: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition/#CSSTransition-prop-onEnter

Comment: @ladyk I tried that as well so I had `in={ props.errorString !== '' }` but no transition still

Comment: Hm, is it possible to provide working codepen example with this part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue with conditionally removing an element wrapped with `<CSSTransition>`. To solve the problem I wrapped the `<CSSTransition>` element with a `<TransitionGroup>` element and used its [childFactory](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group#TransitionGroup-prop-childFactory) prop. The `childFactory` prop can be used like so:

```
  <TransitionGroup
     childFactory={child => React.cloneElement(child)}
  >
    <CSSTransition timeout={400} classNames={errorTransition}>
      <span> {props.errorString} </span>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
```